# Excel vba macro that copies one cell and pastes to another with prepended string

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an Excel VBA script that copies one cell and then pastes this to another column with the string "Notes: " in front of the pasted contents.  My code so far has a few issues but looks like this.

The line I am working on is `Range("A" & (iCounter + 1)).PasteSpecial`.  The output would look like:  `Notes: contents of pasted cell`

```
Sub TEST()
'
'Step1:  Declare your variables.
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim iCounter As Long
    Dim totalRows As Long
    Dim Str1 As String
    Str1 = "NOTES:  "
'Step 2: Define last populated row
    totalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Step 3:  Define the target Range.
    Set MyRange = Range("A1:A" & (totalRows))
'Step 4:  Start reverse looping through the range.
    For iCounter = MyRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    
'Step 5: Copy and Paste columns
        Range("G" & (iCounter)).Copy
        Range("A" & (iCounter + 1)).PasteSpecial
        
'Step 6: Increment the counter down
    Next iCounter
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A" & (iCounter + 1)) = Str1 & Range("G" & (iCounter))`

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner.  This works but is there a way to create this all in one line?  Right now, I have it in two like this.  

   `Range("A" & (iCounter + 1)).PasteSpecial`
   `Range("A" & (iCounter + 1)) = Str1 & Range("G" & (iCounter))`

Comment: That one line does everything for step 5.  You can remove the copy paste lines.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner.  I have to run but will check in about an hour.  Thank you so much for your help!